# How to allow validation to pass with space in between words

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am validating inputs for special characters in my angular app. I want the space between words to pass this test. I am new to regex.

Here is the test

```
  it('should test for special charcter', () => {
    let format = /[ `!@#$%^&*()+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/;
    expect(format.test("Hello Angular")).toEqual(false);

  })
```

To make the test pass It must return `false`, can someone tell how to modify format such as that it catches all the special characters except `underscore` and `space` between two words.

Comment: It is har to understand what you mean. You want to allow special chars or not?

Comment: Please fix your code.

Comment: Hi  gkucmierz , I want to change the format variable such that it allows space between words, suppose I pass "Hello World" or "Hello Angular" , It must pass the test. format.test returns true when it has found any special chars that is not allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern works fine

```js
 var pattern=/[`!@#$%^&*()+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]/g
 var str="Hello Angular js"
 re=pattern.test(str)
 console.log(re)

 var str="Hello Angular_js"
 re1=pattern.test(str)
 console.log(re1)

 var str="Hello Angular%js"
 re2=pattern.test(str)
 console.log(re2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the space from your regex, and regarding the underscore your regex match this as it's not mentioned in the pattern

```
[`!@#$%^&*()+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]
```

it matches all special character mentioned in the regex, except space and underscore